# Private chat with SignalR

Tags: signalr

I would like to know if is possible to create a chat for private conversation like gmail chat or hotmail..
How can I ensure that only client A talks with client B?
How can I ensure that only logged clients can talk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can create a unique "Group" each time a user initiates a chat with another user (or set of users). Then when you send messages to that group only those users would receive the message. You could also layer more security in front of sending messages to a group to ensure that the person sending the message is allowed to send a message to that group.

Comment: Nice, but how can I make this security layer? I've tried to use Session to verify if the user is allowed but it doesn't work. Session is always null and I could not make it work.

Comment: When the chat group was started you need to create metadata about that chat group. One of the things is list of people invited to the chat (by user id let's say). When a call comes in to send a message to a particular chat group, you verify the current caller is in the list of users who were invited to the target chat group.

Comment: No, it's really going to be specific to your domain space. You can take a look at JabbR source code for some inspiration on how they maintain metadata about chat rooms, admins, etc. https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

Comment: what if an Admin can do one to one chat with multiple users, here assigning group will send message to all users. Any idea pls??

Answer (score 9):

Try this application for Private chat with SignalR

Description of Application:
http://www.aspbucket.com/2016/03/implement-of-private-one-to-one-chat.html

Download link
https://github.com/shivam01990/SignalR-private-one-to-one-chat

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at `ChatWithTracking` in [Basic chat sample](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chatwithtracking), that's a great starting point for IM setup

p.s: updated the link; using a search query in case they change the repo structure again

Comment: Damn, the URL 404's. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: @roman Please update the answer as this Url is landing in middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Each client connecting to a hub passes a unique connection id. You can retrieve this value in the Context.ConnectionId property of the hub context. If your application needs to map a user to the connection id and persist that mapping, you can use one of the following:

1. [In-memory storage](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#inmemory), such as a dictionary
2. [SignalR group](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#groups) for each user
3. [Permanent, external storage](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#database), such as a database table or Windows Azure table

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections